# Converting large amounts of JSON to CSV on macOS

Tags: macos, file-conversion, csv, json

I want to convert some 20mb+ JSON files to CSV.

Tried using webapps like https://konklone.io/json/ or https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm but they just crash.

So how can I use other tools to do such conversions?

Comment: Not really an answer but the Macs come with Python so you could create a program to do it!

Answer (score 5):

`jq` works quite well for this, you can install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). Specific usage depends on the structure of your JSON file, the accepted answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570548/convert-json-array-into-csv has details which should help to get started.

---

If you don't have or use Homebrew you do not need it in order the get `jq`, as a precompiled binary is available at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/. It's not packaged and once downloaded as e.g. `jq-osx-amd64`, I did the following in Terminal:

```
cd Downloads
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine jq-osx-amd64
mv jq-osx-amd64 jq
chmod +x jq
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo mv -nv jq /usr/local/bin/
```

As `/usr/local/bin/` is already in the `PATH`/`path` passed to the the `shell` in Terminal, just typing `jq` and pressing enter will run it.

The website has [Tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and [Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) links too.

Comment: Is there a wrapper for `jq` that can handle any JSON file without having to specify its structure? 

When dealing with large files with a somewhat unpredictable  structure, it's not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Other than some poor experiences you've had with the web-based converters, you've not indicated what your preferences are for programming language; e.g. Python, JavaScript, shell, etc. There are **many** options available, and it's really a matter of finding one that's in your "comfort zone".

Search engines are great for identifying options for something like this. For example, if you want to do this in Python, [this search may help](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=JSON+to+CSV+conversion+Python&ia=web). A more language-neutral search may be to [search github for JSON to CSV converters](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=JSON+to+CSV+conversion+github&t=ffnt&ia=web).

I tend to do these things from the command line, or in small scripts. I've tried [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) and I've tried [`Miller` (aka`mlr`)](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller). `jq` has a larger following, but I have a preference for `Miller` because I get results I need without too much effort... but YMMV. One other thing: If you decide to try `Miller` you should file this link to the ["Cookbook" page for `Miller`](http://johnkerl.org/miller-releases/miller-4.3.0/doc/cookbook.html)... it's not advertised well, but I find it useful 'cause I'm a cook :)

Answer (score -4):

You can create a free account at [Gigasheet](https://gigasheet.co) and upload JSON files up to 10GB. It will flatten and convert to CSV which you can then export.

Full disclosure, I'm a co-founder at Gigasheet.